# i want to send only value in json out put

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am working nodejs app with amazon S3 bucket to upload
Now i am trying to get the list of uploaded objects from the same folder from S3 bucket.
I can able to get the list of objects like in the below format but can able to filter it and send it to json. Below is the code i tried it out but getting undefined. Can any one help me out.

```
var url = data.Contents.map(result => result.key)
            console.log(url)
```

I want to sent only key value as a json format from below data..

```
{
    "data": {
        "IsTruncated": false,
        "Contents": [
            {
                "Key": "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.zip",
                "LastModified": "2021-08-05T04:57:26.000Z",
                "ETag": "\"a0172e2e22ddfef7c8379fc876c667bc\"",
                "Size": xxx,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
            },
            {
                "Key": "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/",
                "LastModified": "2021-08-13T08:21:16.000Z",
                "ETag": "\"xxx"",
                "Size": 0,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
            },
            {
                "Key": "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.png",
                "LastModified": "2021-08-13T08:24:03.000Z",
                "ETag": "\"xxx"",
                "Size": xxx,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
            },
            {
                "Key": "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.png",
                "LastModified": "2021-08-13T08:24:16.000Z",
                "ETag": "\"xxx\"",
                "Size": xxx,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "xxx",
        "Prefix": "xxx",
        "MaxKeys": 1000,
        "CommonPrefixes": [],
        "KeyCount": 4
    }
}
```

i want to sent out put like below

```
{
    "status": true,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "depoUsers": [
        [
            key1,
            key2,
            key3,
            key4
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself....i tried to copy one array item to another using push
sharing the code for your reference if any one need

Hope this will help someone....like me who struggled like me

```
var imagesURL = [];
data.Contents.forEach(function (obj, index) {
imagesURL.push('https://xxxxxxx/' + obj.Key)
console.log('https://xxxxxxx//' + obj.Key);
})
console.log(imagesURL)
```